# How to calculate average response time (exclude weekends, holidays, non working hours) MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, response-time

I am trying to calculate average response time (`excluding weekends: Saturday, Sunday and particular dates for holidays and non working hours(10:00AM to 06:00PM)`) but couldn't figure out how to do that, below is the schema of documents:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc91170b15e1f7ae332b9fe"),
    "actions": {
        "created" : ISODate("2019-11-07T07:44:48.799Z"),
        "accepted" : ISODate("2019-11-12T07:44:48.799Z")
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc929bffc638655004a691e"),
    "actions": {
        "created" : ISODate("2019-11-06T09:28:31.039Z"),
        "accepted" : ISODate("2019-11-12T04:48:09.054Z")
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dca3b2a6e78f16598ae462b"),
    "actions": {
        "created" : ISODate("2019-11-12T04:55:06.520Z"),
        "accepted" : ISODate("2019-11-12T04:55:06.520Z")
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dca3bc4dd8d4fe1b0b1b15e"),
    "actions": {
        "created" : ISODate("2019-11-12T04:57:40.396Z"),
        "accepted" : ISODate("2019-11-12T04:57:40.396Z")
    }
}
```

Query that I am using doesn't exclude non working days and hours:

```js
db.claims.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            total_time_count: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $ifNull: ['$actions.accepted', 0] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            total_time: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $ifNull: ['$actions.accepted', 0] },
                        { $subtract: ['$actions.accepted', '$actions.created'] },
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            average_response_time: {
                $cond: [
                    { $gt: ['$total_time_count', 0] },
                    { $divide: ['$total_time', '$total_time_count'] },
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

If anyone has worked on similar scenario, please post in answer.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry mate I don’t have the time to fix this for you. Take a look at this api
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/

Comment: Hey @Ihsan Müjdeci, thanks for the answer, I know the dateOfWeek, but I don't know how to create range for the dates

Comment: This is not the answer to this question.